# Integrating a PHP function In Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

I am new to Node.js, and I am trying to integrate a function I was able to do in PHP in some other project, creating an admin route so that when a regular user logs in, it takes the user to the user dashboard. When the admin logs in, it takes the user to the admin dashboard.

```
class AdminRouteProtect
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()){
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
                return $next($request);
            } else{
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any tries in Node that did not work?

Comment: I tried working my way through the login schema but it only ended in more fraustration...

Comment: I am just trying to integrate an AdminProtect route or function so that the admin user has access to certain views that a random user doesn't

Comment: I believe you need to provide more details on whether you are going with the MVC approach or you want to create REST API and use React js on FE. But according to what I see, you can easily go with [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) plus [Session middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)

Comment: I would recommend that you post a question on how to solve your attempts in node instead, if the rest of the application is written in node. Nodejs is perfectly capable of handling this so involving another technology/language for this specific feature seems like the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Yes sir i want to go with ExpressJS plus Session middleware.. How to go about it is where i am stuck

Comment: You need to try it yourself and show an effort. We can assist with mistakes you make but we cannot write you an application from scratch.